# remove contact from a specific group in android

Tags: android, android-contacts

I am making an android app, I want to remove a contact from a specific group not to delete contact just remove from the group, I have group id and contact id, can anyone please tell me the query to do this,
I want to implement something like Delete contact_id=1 from group_id=2

Answer (score 1):

Contacts are linked to groups with ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership records. You can use something like this to delete contact from group:

```
private void deleteContactFromGroup(long contactId, long groupId)
{
    ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    String where = ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + "=" + groupId + " AND "
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.RAW_CONTACT_ID + "=?" + " AND "
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.MIMETYPE + "='"
            + ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE + "'";

    for (Long id : getRawContactIdsForContact(contactId))
    {
        try
        {
            cr.delete(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI, where,
                    new String[] { String.valueOf(id) });
        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

private HashSet<Long> getRawContactIdsForContact(long contactId)
{
    HashSet<Long> ids = new HashSet<Long>();

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
              new String[]{RawContacts._ID},
              RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
              new String[]{String.valueOf(contactId)}, null);

    if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst())
    {
        do
        {
            ids.add(cursor.getLong(0));
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
    }

    return ids;
}
```

Note that when you perform delete, you should specify RAW_CONTACT_ID instead of CONTACT_ID. So you need to query all raw contact ids for specified contact.

Also you may need to consider account data. In that case change querying for contact ids to something like that:

```
Uri rawContactUri = RawContacts.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon()
            .appendQueryParameter(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_NAME, accountName)
            .appendQueryParameter(RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE, accountType).build();

Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(rawContactUri,
            new String[] { RawContacts._ID }, RawContacts.CONTACT_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(contactId) }, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static Uri addContactToGroup(String rawContactId,String groupId)
    {
        try
        {

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(Data.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContactId);
            values.put(GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID, groupId);
            values.put(Data.MIMETYPE, GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE);

            return getContentResolver.insert(Data.CONTENT_URI, values);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {}
        return Uri.EMPTY;
    }
```

//-----------------------------------

```
public static int removeContactFromGroup(String contactId,String groupId)
{
    try
    {
        String where = Data.CONTACT_ID + " = ? AND " + Data.MIMETYPE + " = ? AND " + GroupMembership.GROUP_ROW_ID + " = ?";
        String[] args = {contactId, GroupMembership.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE, groupId};
        return getContentResolver.delete(Data.CONTENT_URI, where, args);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {}
    return 0;
}
```